# How to get a carriage return (newline) in directlua (tex.sprint) inside a QRCode?

Tags: line-breaking, qrcode, directlua

How can one get a carriage return at the end of each line (Lualatex) ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nolinks,forget]{qrcode}%
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Space}[0]{\ }% 
\newcommand{\CarriageReturn}[0]{\?}%
\qrset{height=2.5cm}

\qrcode[version=5]{
    \directlua{
        for i,p in ipairs( table.pack(1,2,3) )
        do
        tex.sprint (tostring(p),"\Space line \Space then \Space carriage \Space return" \CarriageReturn)
        end
    }
}% 

% Doesn't work:  tex.sprint([[\noexpand\newline]])
% Doesn't work:  \CarriageReturn
% Doesn't work:  empty line

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\noexpand\n` to print a newline character (`\n` in a lua string) through `\directlua` within a document. Adjusting your example we get the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nolinks,forget]{qrcode}%
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Space}[0]{\ }%

\qrset{height=2.5cm}

\qrcode[version=5]{
    \directlua{
        for i,p in ipairs( table.pack(1,2,3) )
        do
        tex.sprint (tostring(p),"\Space line \Space then \Space carriage \Space return\noexpand\n")
        end
    }
}%

\end{document}
```